# Creating a Responsive input field between other elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having trouble getting my search input to act responsively in my header.

In my **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wIpav)** I have a basic header, Logo to the left, Search bar in the middle and navigation buttons on the right. My goal is to get the Search / input bar in the middle to be responsive and stretch to fill the space between the logo and the navigation buttons with some left/right margin.

In my attempts I haven't been able to replicate the basic reponsiveness of the input at the bottom set to 100%.

****How would you approach this problem?****

**http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wIpav**

---

My input:

```
<div class="navigation">

<div class="head-search">
  This input should be responsive
  <input class="txtinput" type="text"/>
    <img src="http://leongaban.com/_stack/images/search_button.png" alt="search"/>
</div>

<nav id="user-actions">
    <ul>
        <li class="btn-blue user-action" data-btn="login" data-pane="login">Log In</li>
        <li class="btn-purple user-action" data-btn="signup" data-pane="signup">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.navigation {
    width: auto; float:right; margin:0px; list-style:none; background:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.head-search {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

.head-search input {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    /* max-width: 290px; */
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}
```

Any and all tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logo on left and navigation on right size have fixed then you can achieve the responsive search bar with following code:

e.g.  your logo width 150px and Navigation width 400px

```
.navigation {
    width: 100%; 
    margin:0px 0 20px ; 
    list-style:none; 
    background:#ccc;
    width:100%;
}
.logo{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}
.head-search {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 400px 0 150px;
}

.head-search input {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    /* max-width: 290px; */
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}

#user-actions{
    width:400px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Cool, I was able to get this to work like so: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wIpav still could use some adjusting, but I'll pick your answer :) thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/fBDhw

I needed to setup % on all the elements in the header, the logo, search bar and navigation buttons... it's not the prettiest codepen, but you should be able to see what I did.

I can't check my own answer for a day so if someone else comes up with a cleaner solution I'll check theirs instead!